# @Transactional do not catch Jackson exception in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I wanna make one transaction per REST query, the REST query is composed from JSON data that is parsed on the fly by Jackson 2. During "parsing" objects instanciation from JSON data, i make some inputs into database through Spring Repository. everything is working nicely expcept for when some database constraints are not respected @Transactional do not catch exception and do not rollback. how i could solve this problem, above you find the code:

UploadData class contains some entity classes in order to parse JSON data and it saves data in database.

**Controller.java**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploaddata", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Reponse uploaddata(@RequestBody UploadData post) throws JsonProcessingException {
    if (messages != null) {
        return new Reponse(-1, messages);
    }

    try {
        return new Reponse(0, post);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Reponse(1, Static.getErreursForException(e));
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.repositories" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.test.entities" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }
}
```

UploadData.java

```
public class UploadData {
    @JsonProperty("ADDEDDATA")
    private AddedData ADDEDDATA;

}
```

Comment: (De)Serialization happens outside the scope of a transaction. The constsruction of the `UploadData` object happens before the methods is invoked and the conversion of the `Response` to JSON after the method has ended. So both things happen outside the transaction. Also a `@Transactional` controller is, imho, ugly as it should be the service layer and not the web layer that drives the transaction.

Comment: please can you give me some recommandations over this problem please ? it is possible to set transaction juste before the Deserialization begins ?

Comment: No not really, not without making the whole request transactional ni a filter. Which would make every request transactional. As stated IMHO you have a wrong layer for the transaction, so you might need to rethink some things.